# Query to sum different columns from different table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables where i am trying to join them and get their sum from two tables and add the two sum from tables.

Here i have a SQL Fiddle for the structure of my Query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb00bc/3/0

I want the output something like this:

```
emp_id   firstname  middlename  lastname    name_ext    SUM(amount_paid)    SUM(salary_paid) SUM(total) 

  1        test        test        test        test          300                  500             800
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query. a subquery with the totals group by employee id will be joined by your tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_user.firstname,
  tbl_user.middlename,
  tbl_user.lastname,
  tbl_user.name_ext,
  t3.amount_paid,
  t3.salary_paid,
  t3.total
FROM tbl_user
INNER JOIN tbl_salary ON tbl_user.employee_id = tbl_salary.employee_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_overtime ON tbl_overtime.employee_id = tbl_salary.employee_id
left join
  (select t1.employee_id
       , SUM(coalesce(t2.amount_paid, 0)) as amount_paid
       , SUM(coalesce(t1.salary_paid, 0)) as salary_paid
       , SUM(coalesce(t2.amount_paid, 0))  + SUM(coalesce(t1.salary_paid, 0)) as total
     from tbl_salary t1
     left join tbl_overtime t2 on t2.employee_id = t1.employee_id
     group by t1.employee_id) as t3 on t3.employee_id = tbl_user.employee_id
```

Comment: updated with coalesce() for null values during left join

Comment: @Metal hey.. can you help me again ?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6baf3/2 i have updated sql fiddle. how can i add only those who have status = 0?

Comment: @JcJohn, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6baf3/20/0, check this `where` clause should be after from, join tables and before group by

Answer (score 1):

**No need to subquery**, just `SUM` the values and `GROUP BY tbl_user`

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_user.firstname,
tbl_user.middlename,
tbl_user.lastname,
tbl_user.name_ext,
sum(coalesce(tbl_overtime.amount_paid,0)),
sum(coalesce(tbl_salary.salary_paid,0)),
sum(coalesce(tbl_salary.salary_paid,0)+coalesce(tbl_overtime.amount_paid,0))
FROM tbl_user
INNER JOIN tbl_salary ON tbl_user.employee_id = tbl_salary.employee_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_overtime ON tbl_overtime.employee_id = tbl_salary.employee_id
GROUP BY tbl_user.firstname,
tbl_user.middlename,
tbl_user.lastname,
tbl_user.name_ext
```

Comment: another great answer @Roy

Comment: hey can you help me again ?

Comment: what do you need @JcJohn?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6baf3 please take a look in my link. i have duplicate entries and i want to avoid adding those status with having status  = 1

Comment: i have a problem regarding some left join was being doubled if it was empty from other table ?

Comment: If I run the query into the sqlfiddle you made, there's no duplicates, please share the correct build

Comment: i have another situation where im putting status in the query and for that status. i want with status = 0 will be added

Comment: So, share the new situation and explain it better.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6baf3 thats the new situation. I want to add those data only with condition of tbl_overtime.status = 0 and tbl_salary.status = 0.

Comment: i made a condition where tbl_salary.status = 0 , also i want to add the tbl_overtime.status = 0 but it gives me few data,  i want all the data

Comment: THere's no query on that link, share the query with the new condition